# How to SELECT [temp table1] = [subselect 1], [temp table2] = [subselect 2] FROM [Stored Procedure]

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns two selects, which I use in a report.
The first select is data to display in tabular format and the second are metadata to display in the report head, like showed below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo. GetReport    
@Input INT
AS 
BEGIN          
   --Get #Metadata    
   -- #Results = f(#Metadata) … compex calculation          
   SELECT * FROM #Results    
   SELECT * FROM #Metadata    
END
```

As the sproc calculation is quite intensive, I would like to prepare the report lines as plain data (in two tables: PrecalcResults and PrecalcMetadata) for some mostly used sproc parameters overnight. 
Lather I would directly select the precalculated vaues or calculate them with the sproc according to the parameters.

For maintenance reasons I would like to use the same sproc to calculate data that would be: 
1.  showed in the report
2.  be stored in PrecalcResults and PrecalcMetadata (with the used parameters)

If I would have single select sproc I would an approach desctibed here:
[Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

As I have multiselect sproc I would like to do something like above but with two tables.
In .net I would do DataSet.Tables[0] and  DataSet.Tables[1]..., but I want to do it in tsql, to run it in daily job.

Is this even possible in MS SQL?

---

I have to apologize myself, from the answer below I can see I was not very clear.
I would like to do implement this functionality as pure TSQL.

Comment: Try searching for "multiple active recordsets" (aka MARS).  You'll need to use the `NextRecordset` method to move from one recordset to the next.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

[It's perfectly fine to return multiple result sets from a single stored procedure as you have suggested.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876146/stored-procedure-return-multiple-result-sets)

Your only potential issue is the limitation of a `TableAdapter` being able to pull both result sets from the stored procedure, [but there's a very simple work-around for that issue.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/03/13/tableadapter-multiple-result-sets.aspx)

Comment: unless it is a temp table, then it will not be found because it only exists on the server

Comment: @bluefeet That hasn't been my experience... that could be an issue with your data access layer, or attempting to reference the temp table on a separate connection...  It should be invisible to the client whether or not the source for a select statement is a temporary or non-temporary table.

Comment: Well it depends on how you are using it, if you have a temp table returning data in a stored proc and you add the stored procedure to a DataSet.xsd file.  My experience is that it is not aware of the temp table at that point since it exists on the server only

Comment: @bluefeet Ah... that's because Visual Studio is taking a short-cut and trying to determine the metadata of your stored procedure without actually executing it, which is where the temporary table causes an issue.  If you were to add [`SET FMTONLY OFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx) to the top of your stored procedure containing the temporary table, it would work as expected.  [Please see this discussion regarding the issue.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/2e8b86eb-9c3d-439f-a904-b457ad9c0a2c/)

Comment: wow that is awesome, I was not aware of that.  I will need to keep it in mind for future projects.